# Select what fields to display in an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data like this:

```
dataArray = [ 
  'index1' => 'value1',
  'index2' => 'value2',
  'index3' => '[
    'index1' => 'value1',
    'index2' => [ 
       'index1' => 'value1',
     ],
    'index3' => 'value3',
  ]
]
```

The dimension of the array is unknown.

I have another array that defines what values from *dataArray* I need to print:

```
maskArray = ['index2', 'index3' => [ 'index1', 'index2' => [ 'index1' ] ]]
```

I need to output an array that match the fields from *maskArray* and *dataArray*, so in this case the output should be:

```
result = [ 
  'index2' => 'value2',
  'index3' => [
    'index1' => 'value1' 
    'index2' => [
      'index1' => 'value1'
    ]
  ]
]
```

In this scenario the *maskArray* is 3 levels deep, but it could be n levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how deep the array could be nested, a recursive solution is probably appropriate. Maybe there are better ones, but I think this is quite short and readable:

```
function recursiveFilter($data, $whiteList)
{
    $results = [];

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        // if the current key is on the whitelist, either as value
        // or as a key (it's a key if it's nested, otherwise a value)
        if(in_array($key, $whiteList) or array_key_exists($key, $whiteList))
        {
            // if the current value is an array and the whitelist
            // has filters for that array, then call this function
            // again with just the relevant portion of data and filters,
            // otherwise just grab the whole value as it is.
            $results[$key] = is_array($value) && isset($whiteList[$key])
                ? recursiveFilter($value, $whiteList[$key])
                : $value;
        }

    }

    return $results;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/16JIJf